# Errno 13 Permission denied в python скомпилированном в .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, pyinstaller

Я хотел что бы код создавал файл .txt с заданным пользователем именем и вносил туда данные но при попытке создания файла в скомпилированном python коде выдаётся ошибка '[Errno 13] Permission denied'
Отрывок кода с записью ниже:
[image: Мой код]

Comment: Чтобы писать всем ко всем юзерам подряд нужны будут админские пермиссии, видимо. Запускаете `exe` от админа?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса